# Content Security Policy (CSP) to Allow XML formatting on Chrome Browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, content-security-policy

After adding a content security policy to my MCV.NET web service:  `default-src 'self'` my Chrome browser no longer formats XML responses.
When I look in the Chrome DevTool's Network tab, it shows calls from the source of "data:" for an inline image, font and style.

How can I safely allow Chrome to format my XML responses?

Would this be safe? `default-src 'self' data: 'unsafe-inline'`

Comment: can you show us the snippet where do you set the content policy?

Comment: What do you mean with "no longer formats XML responses"?

Comment: How do fetch that XML and how do you use it?